# Encountering an "uninitialized constant" error when using the Imgur-api gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to allow a user to upload an image for their profile and have so far gotten the image uploaded to the [root]/tmp/uploads folder. However, I'd like to permanently host images on Imgur rather than Heroku so I've installed the 'imgur-api' gem.

I've followed their documentation, which can be found [here](http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/imgur-api/0.0.4). This is what my upload method looks like in users_controller.rb

```
  def upload
    picture = params[:user][:picture]
    File.open(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'uploads', picture.original_filename), 'wb') do |file|
        file.write(picture.read)
        end
      Imgur::Client.new('8ec4b8a4de10f42')
      Imgur::LocalImage ruby image = Imgur::LocalImage.new(Rails.root.join('tmp', 'uploads', picture.original_filename, title: 'profile'))
      Imgur::Image ruby uploaded = Imgur::Client.upload(image)
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
      @user.update_attribute(:photo_url, uploaded.link)
  end
```

I've pretty much copied and pasted the code from the documentation except for that line with the grave accents (I'm not really sure what that means or if it's a typo), but when I try to update the profile picture, I get a "NameError in UsersController#update - uninitialized constant UsersController::Imgur"

How would I go about initializing this constant? I've searched for this error message but the questions aren't about gems. Do I have to do something akin to #include "imgur-api"?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you `bundle install`?

Comment: Yeah, the gem is listed among the others installed as 'Using imgur-api, 0.0.4'.